# How to get Grid by name in a non-ui thread - Windows Phone

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8

In my wp app, I am using silverlight 8.1 and

I have this grid in my **MainPage.xaml**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        ...
```

I need to get it from another file and from another thread using this

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
... do some work on UI here 
}
```

how can I get it programmatically?

I tried with MainPage.LayourRoot but it does not find LayoutRoot.

Comment: Using the Dispatcher you get the reference of all elements populating the UI. I don't understand the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got the point. There is a way which tells what page the user is currently on:

```
var currentPage = ((App)Application.Current).RootFrame.Content as PhoneApplicationPage;
```

You simply get it and cast to a specific page type such as `MainPage` and then you are able to get reference to all visual elements with `x:Name` property.

Please tell me whether this code worked. I can't debug it since I'm no loger use SDK 8 and I'm sure this is not working on WinRT.